# How to to set Region when deploying Firebase Cloud Functions (2nd gen)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am setting up a Firebase project with functions organised in separate files. I am trying this out with 2nd gen functions.

Looking at the documentation, it seems like it has not been updated for 2nd gen as the example code functions are 1st gen:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions?gen=2nd#write_functions_in_multiple_files

Even so, everything is working fine using this simple setup:

**index.ts:**

```ts
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'
import addAmessage from './api/addAmessage'
import app from './onCall/app'

initializeApp()

exports.addAmessage = addAmessage

exports.app = app
```

And in the addAmessage.ts file I use the Firebase example function only adding the setGlobalOptions:

**api/addAmessage.ts:**

```ts
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'
import { setGlobalOptions } from 'firebase-functions/v2'

setGlobalOptions({ region: 'europe-west3' })
// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into
// Firestore under the path /messages/:documentId/original
const addAmessage = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const message = req.query.text

  if (message !== undefined) {
    // Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    const writeResult = await getFirestore()
      .collection('messages')
      .add({ message })
    // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
    res.json({ result: `Message with ID: ${ writeResult.id } added.` })
  }
})

export default addAmessage
```

With just one Function this works fine, but since I set use the setGlobalOptions in my other functions files also I get a warning in the emulator console:

"Calling setGlobalOptions twice leads to undefined behavior"

I originally put the setGlobalOptions method in my index.ts file but then it was ignored.

So, I would love to only have to setGlobalOptions once, but how is it done correctly with multiple files?

Comment: What are you seeing that leads you to believe that `setGlobalOptions method in my index.ts file [...] was ignored.` ?

The `setGlobalOptions` is outside `addAmessage` and running it from index.ts should be the same thing. Are you compiling typescript before starting the emulator?

Comment: @Chris I am seeing, that the functions are deployed in default (us-central) location, when setGlobalOptions is called in index.ts, that why I believe it is ignored.
But, I actually landed at 2nd Gen not being ready for my Production yet anyways (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76306434/unpredictable-urls-with-firebase-cloud-functions-2nd-gen/76306782#76306782)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and incase anyone is still struggling with this, you can pass an options object to the callable function. One of the options is `region`, which you can set as required.

Here is the code that should work :

```
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'

// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into
// Firestore under the path /messages/:documentId/original
const addAmessage = onRequest({region: 'europe-west3'}, async (req, res) =>
{
    // Grab the text parameter.
    const message = req.query.text

    if (message !== undefined) {
        // Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
        const writeResult = await getFirestore()
            .collection('messages')
            .add({ message })
        // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
        res.json({ result: `Message with ID: ${ writeResult.id } added.` })
    }
})

export default addAmessage
```

Answer (score 12):

I've just run into the same issue and was able to solve it by changing the export, making your code look like:

**index.ts**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'
import { setGlobalOptions } from 'firebase-functions/v2'

initializeApp()

setGlobalOptions({ region: 'europe-west3' })

export { addAmessage } from './api/addAmessage'
export { import } app from './onCall/app'
```

**api/addAmessage.ts**

```
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'

// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into
// Firestore under the path /messages/:documentId/original
export const addAmessage = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const message = req.query.text

  if (message !== undefined) {
    // Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    const writeResult = await getFirestore()
      .collection('messages')
      .add({ message })
    // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
    res.json({ result: `Message with ID: ${ writeResult.id } added.` })
  }
})
```

you can still override the global options or append to them in your function if needed by adding the options to your onRequest.

```
export const addAmessage = onRequest({ minInstances: 1 }, async (req, res) => {
```

As to why this is, I do not know and maybe someone can explain it further.

Comment: Hey Joris, it doesn't seems to work for me. What version of firebase-tools are you using ?

Comment: firebase tools: 12.4.0, firebase-functions: ^4.4.1, firebase-admin: ^11.9.0, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Joris. I had to leave 2nd Gen for later because of the unpredictable URL issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76306434/unpredictable-urls-with-firebase-cloud-functions-2nd-gen/76306782#76306782), but when it matures, I will try out your solution.

Comment: I have the same issue but this solution does not work for me. The `setGlobalOptions` setting gets ignored in other files, unless I repeat it in the other files, which leads to the warning about calling `setGlobalOptions` twice.

Comment: @Laurent for me it only worked when using the import and then export it again from the index that contains the ```setGlobalOptions```. Other ways of splitting files didn't work for me as well.

Comment: How can you override these settings for a trigger function like `onDocumentCreated` ?

Comment: @Joris what is the exact syntax for this? how do you export a function that was just imported? and in this case, do you repeat the `setGlobalOptions` in the other file or not?

Comment: @DavidOort `onDocumentCreated` should have an overload that takes `opts` as a first argument, so write `onDocumentCreated({region:'blah'},(event)=>{...})`

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

config/functions.ts

```
import { defineString } from 'firebase-functions/params';
import { setGlobalOptions } from 'firebase-functions/v2';

// Gen2 global options
setGlobalOptions({
  region: defineString('REGION'),
});
```

index.ts

```
import './config/functions'; // Set gen2 global options
```

.env:

```
REGION="northamerica-northeast1"
```

Just tested it real quick by deploying a single callable function:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:myCallableFunction --project {project_id}
```

Terminal Output:

```
i  functions: creating Node.js 18 (2nd Gen) function myCallableFunction(northamerica-northeast1)...
```

Note: the only function where I need to explicitly set region at the function level is [cloud storage triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events?gen=2nd#setting-location). It seems to ignore the global options. Not sure why that is.