# Unpredictable URLs with Firebase Cloud Functions 2nd gen

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am used to Firebase Functions and now trying to set up a project with Firebase Cloud Functions 2nd Gen.

When I deploy my functions they do not get the predictable URLs that I know from 1st gen (like: `https://europe-west1-[project-slug].cloudfunctions.net/[function-name]`), but rather some weird URLs like this one: `https://[function-name]-kbnn7zbc7q-uc.a.run.app`).

I can't find any mentions of this in the documentation and I expect there may be a setting to get a more predictable scheme for functions URLs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of now at least, there is also a deterministic URL for functions.

The [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http#url) adds this:

> Both 1st gen and 2nd gen functions have assigned URLs that have the following format. These URLs have a deterministic format, meaning that you can predict what the URL will be before you deploy the function:

```
https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME
```

Firebase (unhelpfully) shows the non-deterministic URL. You can see the deterministic URL in the GCP console for functions if you are like me and don't completely trust the URL pattern above.

Comment: I just checked this solution out too. Works! Thanks Brent

Answer (score 5):

There is currently no such option.  Cloud Functions 2nd gen is actually built on top of another cloud service called Cloud Run.  The URL you're seeing is a Cloud Run URL (note `run.app`).

There are mentions in GCP Cloud Functions doc about this URL.  In particular, in this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http), it says:

> Note: Currently, function URLs in Cloud Functions (2nd gen) use a non-deterministic format, meaning you cannot predict your function URL before deployment, though the URL remains stable after deployment. In a future release, function URLs will be updated to be both stable and deterministic.

Also in [gcloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-gcloud):

> Note: Currently, function URLs in Cloud Functions (2nd gen) use a non-deterministic format, meaning you cannot predict your function URL before deployment, though the URL remains stable after deployment. In a future release, function URLs will be updated to be both stable and deterministic.

Firebase just uses the underlying GCP products, so it inherits the same properties of the generated URL.

Comment: Thanks  @Doug that explains. I guess 2nd gen is not yet ready for my use then.

Comment: Note that this answer is no longer correct, 2nd gen CF now generate 2 URL, and one of them is deterministic.

Comment: This might worth a quick read though. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1447